# CKEditor to Send Emails with ASP.NET [vb] - Issues with Special Characters

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ckeditor

I have a standard HTML page with an CKEditor on it wrapped in a form.
The form submits (POSTS) to Send_Emails.aspx

Send_Emails.aspx reads the content of the FCKEditor into a variable

```
Dim html As String = Request.Form("ck_content")
```

Then it sends an email.

**Problem**

Characters such as:

```
Â -> this seems to show as a special character for blank spaces/carriage returns
â€™ -> this seems to show as apostrophe's
```

Can you reccomend some methods to cleanze my post data of these non-standard characters?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to strip unwanted characters by using this function:

```
function removeMSWordChars(str) {
    var myReplacements = new Array();
    var myCode, intReplacement;
    myReplacements[8216] = 39;
    myReplacements[8217] = 39;
    myReplacements[8220] = 34;
    myReplacements[8221] = 34;
    myReplacements[8212] = 45;
    for(c=0; c<str.length; c++) {
        var myCode = str.charCodeAt(c);
        if(myReplacements[myCode] != undefined) {
            intReplacement = myReplacements[myCode];
            str = str.substr(0,c) + String.fromCharCode(intReplacement) + str.substr(c+1);
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```